# Sould i tag a hotfix release in production using GIT scm

Tags: git, deployment, versioning, scm

We have weekly planned release cycle. Following standard semantic versioning system. Like first week V3.0.0, next V3.0.1 patch release, next week V3.1.0 minor release.

Apart from the above planned releases we have N daily bugfixes and hot fixes.

My question is how do I maintain the semantic version pattern?
Should I deploy and tag every patch every time? Or one tag per day which may contain N hotfixes at the end of the day?

Answer (score 5):

In semantic versioning every release should be tagged, every tag should increase exactly one of the numbers by one (and set the following numbers, if any, to zero), and tags should never be reused for any reason. Other than that you are free to release as often as you like. If you release very often you may want to include some code to easily increment the correct version component.

Comment: Deploying patches more frequently on production increased chance of more conflicts and lack of regression.for  Example today's 4 patch deployment produced a new bug. 4th one was having conflicts with first hence some changes get overridden.

Comment: If you don't test before releasing all bets are off. That has nothing to do with semantic versioning.